# How to Use bash to read a file and then execute

Tags: bash

I have export txt file in linux as

```
2021-11-10T02:54:18+00:00   172.31.0.110    51.146.201.110  running david@mail.com  m5.2xlarge  vpc-95525af1
2021-11-23T17:40:04+00:00   10.0.0.254      192.168.10.20   running rob@mail.com    t2.micro    vpc-068cf656faf214df2
```

I looking for bash script that read from the  file, if the date is less then 30 days from the current date, then send email as row 5 . email subset: You vm is .... body
You vm is over 5... please power off ....

Thanks

Comment: Row 5? there are only 2 here.

Comment: The script will use the email address from the line .

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
IFS=$'\r\n'
GLOBIGNORE='*'
text=($(cat "export.txt")) # NAME OF THE FILE
for i in "${text[@]}"; do
  obj_ip=$(echo $i | cut -d $'\t' -f 2)
  obj_another_ip=$(echo $i | cut -d $'\t' -f 3)
  obj_email=$(echo $i | cut -d $'\t' -f 5)
  obj_datetime=$(echo $i | cut -d $'\t' -f 1)
  obj_name=$(echo $i | cut -d $'\t' -f 6)

  timeago='30 days ago' #EDIT TO MATCH YOUR IDEAS
  dtSec=$(date --date "$obj_datetime" +'%s')
  taSec=$(date --date "$timeago" +'%s') 

  if [ $dtSec -lt $taSec ]; then
    to_send_text="Your VM $obj_name with IP $obj_ip is Too Old, please power off"
    mail -s $to_send_text your@email.com
    echo $to_send_text
  fi
done
```

Comment: You are amazing ,,, It is working !!! > Thanks

Comment: Please like my answer if it was helpful